# Raising and lowering indices to second order

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, perturbation-theory, approximations

If I consider a metric perturbed to second order, $$g_{\mu\nu}= \eta_{\mu\nu} + \lambda h_{\mu\nu}^{(1)} + \lambda^2 h_{\mu\nu}^{(2)},\tag{1}$$ how should I raise and lower indices for a generic tensor? With the unperturbed metric $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ or with the metric up to first order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The objects $h_{\mu\nu}^{(1)}$ and $h_{\mu\nu}^{(2)}$ (and higher order counterparts) are tensors on the background spacetime (i.e. the spacetime you are expanding about). Consequently, their indices are raised and lowered with the background metric, i.e.  the notation ${{h^{(2)}}_{\mu}}^{\nu}$ means ${{h^{(2)}}_{\mu\alpha}} \eta^{\alpha\nu}$.

Of course, full expressions tensors living in the perturbed spacetime have their indices raised and lower by the full metric. In particular

$$ g^{\mu\nu} \neq \eta^{\mu\nu} + \lambda {{h^{(1)}}^{\mu\nu}} + \lambda^2 {{h^{(2)}}^{\mu\nu}}, $$
instead
\begin{align} 
g^{\mu\nu} &= \eta^{\mu\nu} - \lambda {{h^{(1)}}^{\mu\nu}} + \lambda^2 (-{{h^{(2)}}^{\mu\nu}}+ {{h^{(1)}}^{\mu\alpha}}{{{h^{(1)}}_{\alpha}}^{\nu}}) + \mathcal{O}(\lambda^3) 
\\
&= \eta^{\mu\nu} - \lambda {{h^{(1)}}_{\alpha\beta}}\eta^{\alpha\mu}\eta^{\beta\nu} + \lambda^2 (-{{h^{(2)}}_{\alpha\beta}}\eta^{\alpha\mu}\eta^{\beta\nu}+ 
{{h^{(1)}}_{\gamma\alpha}}{{{h^{(1)}}_{\beta\delta}}}\eta^{\alpha\beta}\eta^{\gamma\mu}\eta^{\delta\nu}) + \mathcal{O}(\lambda^3).
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

1. The full GR theory is defined by the metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ and contains a set of the [tensors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor) (wrt. general coordinate transformations), such as e.g. the [Riemann curvature tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_curvature_tensor). Tensors indices are raised and lowered with the $g_{\mu\nu}$ metric.
2. For [perturbation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory) beyond the [linearized theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearized_gravity) one still normally expand the metric as
   $$g_{\mu\nu}~=~\eta_{\mu\nu}+h_{\mu\nu},\tag{A}$$
   where $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ is the background metric. Here $h_{\mu\nu}$ plays the role of OP's full perturbation (1).
3. We now expand the original set of tensors as follows. Tensor indices are here raised and lowered by the background metric $\eta_{\mu\nu}$, e.g.
   $$h^{\mu}{}_{\lambda}~:=~ \eta^{\mu\nu}h_{\nu\lambda}. \tag{B}$$
4. The full inverse metric now reads
   $$ \begin{align}g^{\mu\nu}~:=~&(g^{-1})^{\mu\nu}\cr
   ~=~&\left(\delta^{\mu}_{\lambda}-h^{\mu}{}_{\lambda}+h^{\mu}{}_{\rho}h^{\rho}{}_{\lambda}-h^{\mu}{}_{\sigma}h^{\sigma}{}_{\rho}h^{\rho}{}_{\lambda}+{\cal O}(h^4)\right) \eta^{\lambda\nu}.\end{align} \tag{C}$$

Comment: I don't see why in perturbation theory you are rising with the unperturbed metric (your point 3). In full GR you would raise and lower indices with the full metric, so I suppose you should just expand it to the relevant order.

Comment: Hi @tpet. Thanks for the feedback. The point is to not conflate the 2 notions of tensors.

Comment: Sorry but -1, your attempt to introduce tensor fields based on the global isometry group of a manifold is just nonsensical, and certainly unhelpful in explaining the issue at hand.

Comment: I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the order in $h_{\mu \nu}$ you want your generic tensor to be expanded to. Usually, we don't want higher order terms in $h$, so we raise/lower indices using the unperturbed metric.